# How can I have a user call on a dictionary with the input function in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, variables, input

Im trying to make project where I can type an input of a recipe and how many batches of this particular recipe then adds up all alike ingredients I will need. Im going to have about 100+ recipes to choose from. What would be a better way to do this without using 100+ elif statements.

```
from collections import Counter
c=Counter({})
def format():
    for i in c:
       print(i,round(c[i],2))

def multiply(dict, amount):
    for key in dict:
        dict[key] *= amount
    c.update(dict)

def make():
global c
while True:
    my_input = input('choose formual : ')
    if my_input == 'done':
        break
    elif my_input == 'recipe1':
        batches=float(input('how many : '))
        multiply(recipe1, batches)
    elif my_input == 'recipe2':
        my_input=float(input('how many : '))
        multiply(recipe2, batches)
    else:
        'no fomula with that name. type done if you are finished. '

recipe1={'eggs':2,'milk':37, 'sugar':12}
recipe2={'eggs':3,'milk':14.5, 'sugar':8, 'flour':14.6}

make()
format()
```

So say if I called recipe1 at 3 batches and recipe2 at 5 batches my output is

```
eggs 15.0
milk 154.5
sugar 60.0
flour 43.8
```

This works but not very efficient coding, could anyone point me to a better way to select these recipes? I have only been using python for about a month and a half, so still pretty new to everything. thanks in advance!

Comment: It's always a bad sign if you start to create variables that end with indices (such as `recipe1`, `recipe2`, etc). Consider using a dict of dicts or a list of dicts to include all recipes in single variable. This should also answer your main question.

Comment: ok... I was thinking that too, kinda like taking a json approach. Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug in your code: the `recipe2` choice does not update the variable `batches`. Your example (recipe1 at 3 batches and recipe2 at 5 batches) should give: `{'milk': 183.5, 'sugar': 76.0, 'flour': 73.0, 'eggs': 21.0}`.

Comment: @MarkRogers that has nothing to do with JSON. Don't mix up JSON, which is a text-based serialization format, with nested dicts/lists. It's a common equivocation, but it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use a dictionary `formula -> ingredients` because you can check the existence of a formula easily, and you can return the list of available formulas.

Some minor points:

- `Counter()` initialization does not need an empty dict;
- do not use global variable but parameters (or fields if you are comfortable with classes);
- do not use `dict` or any builtin keyword as a variable name (avoid `format` too);
- use `d.items()` to get the values along with the keys of a dict;
- use format strings to create a nice output;
- check the input for conversion errors (is the input a number?).

I propose the following code:

```
from collections import Counter

def display(c):
    for k, v in c.items():
       print(f"{k:<16}{v:>12.2f}") # k is left aligned, v right aligned, precision 2

def make(ingredients_by_formula):
    c = Counter()
    while True:
        formula = input('Choose formula ("done" to end, "list" to list formulas): ')
        if formula == 'done':
            break
        elif formula == 'list':
            print(list(ingredients_by_formula))
        else:
            try:
                ingredients = ingredients_by_formula[formula]
                amount = float(input('how many : '))
            except KeyError:
                print('no formula with that name!')
            except ValueError:
                print('a number please!')
            else:
                c.update({k: v * amount for k, v in ingredients.items()})

    return c

ingredients_by_formula = {
    'recipe1': {'eggs':2,'milk':37, 'sugar':12},
    'recipe2': {'eggs':3,'milk':14.5, 'sugar':8, 'flour':14.6}
}

display(make(ingredients_by_formula))
```

I used a simple dict comprehension to update the dict: map every key to `amount` times the value.

Comment: wow, thats awesome, thank you so much. This is exactly what im looking for. I haven't learned about 'try, except' yet. Im still fairly new to coding .But will continue to learn everything I can. Thanks I really appreciate it.